# What do female astronauts do on their menstrual cycle?

Tags: medical, astronaut-lifestyle

I know that there is medication to prevent the menstrual cycle, but what side-effects does this entail?

> Does regularly supressing the menstrual cycle pose any health risks to female astronauts?

If the female astronaut's period was allowed to continue, how would zero-Gee conditions effect it?

As a wider question, is it necessary for a woman to menustrate at all (a question I have asked myself *many* times!)?

Comment: This is honestly a fantastic question.

Comment: It's been bugging me for quite a few years to be honest xD

Comment: I remember a passage from Mike Mullane's autobiography, Riding Rockets, where a problem was caused by a packet of tampons spilling into the cabin during STS-41-D in 1984. It's only one data point, and I'm sure there are better sources but I'll have a dig thought the book again. Astronaut biographies are often full of interesting stories that somehow missed the official reports.

Answer (score 7):

Women astronauts [have plenty of tampons available](http://elitedaily.com/news/world/nasa-engineers-asked-sally-ride-if-100-tampons-were-enough-for-a-one-week-mission/641385/) (presumably pads as well). As with other zero-G hygiene issues, I would guess that patience and [wet wipes](http://airandspace.si.edu/collections/artifact.cfm?object=nasm_A19850477007) are indispensable.

Hormonal contraceptives can (somewhat unreliably) suppress menstruation entirely -- a woman who normally uses typical oral contraceptives could probably just skip her placebo week to delay her period on a short space mission.

It's unclear what the long term health effects of use of e.g. [Depo-Provera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depot_medroxyprogesterone_acetate) or [Norplant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norplant) are; Depo usually stops menstruation for three months or longer at a stretch.

Comment: Could you add details answering another facet of this question ; *do* they suppress it or not?

Comment: No, I could not.

Comment: @vedant - any physician will tell you that’s going to be highly variable patient to patient.  There’s also a large trade off between progesterone-only suppression, which is less effective but carries low risk of vascular complications, vs estrogen-containing options.  For highest likelihood of fully suppressing menstruation, an estrogen containing OCP is preferred, but the trade-off is a patient-specific choice informed by other risk factors.  Any medication used long-term on orbit is ground trialed in the months prior to launch so we have some expectations set for efficacy and side effects.